# remove part of string from textarea with click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace, textarea

I have some javascript that adds a product title to a textarea when the user clicks on a "add to basket"-button.

```
<a href="#" class="add-button" data-id="@fieldset.Id" data-producttitle="@fieldset.GetValue("productItemTitle")">Tilføj</a>
```

And the javascript

```
var productTitle = settings.productTitle;           
$(".tilvalg textarea").text($(".tilvalg textarea").text() + productTitle + "\n");
```

How can I remove that line from the textarea if the user click on a remove button for that specific line?

The textarea could look like this:

```
Product name 1
Product name 2
Product name 3
```

if the user have added 3 products

If the user then clicks on "remove" on product 2, the textarea should look like

```
Product name 1
Product name 3
```

I am not quite sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Clicks "remove" on product 2? What do you mean? What remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be advantageous to change your JavaScript to use an array to store the strings (And maybe sort them), and then you can modify your list before outputting it. Something like so:

```
var items = [];

// on click for adding
    items.push(productTitle); // Add item to end of array
    $(".tilvalg textarea").text(items.join('\n')); // Join items by new line and output

// on click for removing
    var index = items.indexOf(productNameToFind); // Find an item in the array
    if(index != -1)
        items.splice(index, index); // Remove item at found index
    $(".tilvalg textarea").text(items.join('\n')); // Join items by new line and output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that

```
$('#YourRemoveButton').on('click', function () {

        var lines = $('#box').val().split(/\n/);
        lines['YourLineIndex - 1 '] = "";
        lines = lines.filter(function(v){return v!==''});
        $("#box").val(lines.join("\n"));

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the position of the caret inside the `textarea` and split the content to see if the current line is exactly the value that you are looking for.

In this example I used the text `TEXT TO REMOVE` as an example:

```js
$('#btn1').click(function() {
  // Get caret position
  cur = $('#ta').prop("selectionStart");
  
  // Save the value of the textarea
  str = $('#ta').val();
  
  beforeCursor = str.substr(0, cur);
  afterCursor = str.substr(cur);
  
  splitted_before = beforeCursor.split("\n")
  splitted_after = afterCursor.split("\n")
  lastline_before = splitted_before.pop();
  firstline_after = splitted_after.shift();
  
  fullline = lastline_before + firstline_after;
  
  if (fullline == "TEXT TO REMOVE") {
    new_str = splitted_before.join("\n") + "\n" + splitted_after.join("\n")
    $('#ta').val(new_str)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="ta" style="width: 450px; height: 250px;"></textarea><br />
<button id="btn1">Remove</button>
```